# Javascript round / floor / toFixed on decimals

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy

I am having an issue with how javascript is dividing and rounding the number.

I have two float , 0.11 and 0.12

I want to calculate the mid of these two numbers and round it to the nearest highest value with 2 decimal price.

For example, if I do this on Calculator

0.11+0.12 / 2 = 0.115, and I need to round it to 0.12 as it is mid or above mid.

If I do this with Javascript, I am not getting an accurate number

Example,

```
var high = parseFloat(0.12);
var low = parseFloat(0.11);

var mid = (high + low) / 2;

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = mid;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = mid.toFixed(2);

var another = mid.toFixed(3);
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML =another;

var last = Math.floor(another)
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML =last;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gzqwbp6c/9/

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the `0.11499999999999999` shows, the result is very slightly less than `0.115`. This is because `0.11` and `0.12` cannot be represented with perfect accuracy using floating-point-numbers.

When you don't want to deal with floating-point-error, it's often easier to work with integers directly. Small integers are represented *exactly* by floating point numbers.

You can multiply by 100 before, and round, to ensure your numbers are integers, and only divide after you get your final result:

```
var a = Math.round(100 * parseFloat("0.12"))        // 12
var b = Math.round(100 * parseFloat("0.11"))        // 11

var mid = (a + b) / 2                               // 11.5.
// 0.5 can be represented exactly in floating point for small numbers.

var midRound = (Math.round(mid) / 100).toFixed(2)   // "0.12"
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to multiply (workout on int part, i.e. find mid, and divide to reconvert to origin):

```
function myMid(high,low, precision){
 var precision=2
 var convFactor = Math.pow(10,precision);
 return 
    (Math.round((low*convFactor+high*convFactor)/2)/convFactor).toFixed(precision);
}
```

Float is not precise, you cant rely on that, you'll have unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

everything `*100` to prevent inaccuracies

`.toFixed()` does the rounding

```js
var a = 0.11;
var b = 0.12;
c = parseFloat((((a*100) + (b*100))/200).toFixed(2));
console.log(c);
```